# Error with deserializing complex Json

Tags: c#, json

I deserialize complex JSON (Spotify Playlist) and get root level values but I cannot get branches values. I Google problem, try different options without success but, I assume its silly mistake or lack of knowledge so therefore just ask for help what I am missing?

My classes are:

```
public class Playlist
{
    public string collaborative { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    //public <ExternalUrls> external_urls { get; set; }     //object
    //public List<Followers> followers { get; set; }        //object
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    //public List<Image> images { get; set; }               //array
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Tracks
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public Item items { get; set; }                        //object
    public string limit { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string offset { get; set; }
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
}
```

And code to deserialize looks like that:

```
StreamReader responseFromServer = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

var dataResponse = responseFromServer.ReadToEnd();
responseFromServer.Close();

var elements = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Playlist>(dataResponse);

RootBuffer.AddRow();
RootBuffer.collaborative = elements.collaborative.ToString();

foreach (Tracks trs in elements.tracks)
{
    TracksBuffer.AddRow();
    TracksBuffer.href = trs.href.ToString()
}
```

Comment: If response comes with list of paylist model. then use 

**var elements = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Playlist>>(dataResponse); **

Comment: I alter that and add for foreach statement and don't have any response:
var elements = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Playlist>>(dataResponse);

foreach (Playlist e in elements)

Comment: Could you post a sample JSON you receive?

Comment: ok, without the json it's hard to reproduce the problem. good luck.

Comment: Thank you for help, because its too big to put to this post so I put on [onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7424D9E946244A21!1244&authkey=!ALdJx2ntBj1GR7A&ithint=file%2ctxt), there is no sensitive data so I can share it.

Comment: cool, thanks. I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

I genereated the classes using this excellent site: [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)

And used your existing deserialization code successfully with the following classes. It populated all the data including the child collections (brace yourself, it's a long one):

```
public class Playlist
{
    public bool collaborative { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public ExternalUrls external_urls { get; set; }
    public Followers followers { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Owner owner { get; set; }
    public bool @public { get; set; }
    public string snapshot_id { get; set; }
    public Tracks tracks { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalUrls
{
    public string spotify { get; set; }
}

public class Followers
{
    public object href { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public object height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public object width { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalUrls2
{
    public string spotify { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public ExternalUrls2 external_urls { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalUrls3
{
    public string spotify { get; set; }
}

public class AddedBy
{
    public ExternalUrls3 external_urls { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalUrls4
{
    public string spotify { get; set; }
}

public class Image2
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public string album_type { get; set; }
    public List<object> available_markets { get; set; }
    public ExternalUrls4 external_urls { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Image2> images { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalUrls5
{
    public string spotify { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public ExternalUrls5 external_urls { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalIds
{
    public string isrc { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalUrls6
{
    public string spotify { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public Album album { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
    public List<object> available_markets { get; set; }
    public int disc_number { get; set; }
    public int duration_ms { get; set; }
    public bool @explicit { get; set; }
    public ExternalIds external_ids { get; set; }
    public ExternalUrls6 external_urls { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int popularity { get; set; }
    public string preview_url { get; set; }
    public int track_number { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string added_at { get; set; }
    public AddedBy added_by { get; set; }
    public bool is_local { get; set; }
    public Track track { get; set; }
}

public class Tracks
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public object next { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public object previous { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I had all classes defined just for purpose of this post limit to two. I cannot get java deserializer to work, and dont know why? I think I will try to install newtonsoft json.

Comment: Java? I thought it was all about C# :-). Anyway sorry it didn't help you